# Как определить что произошел импорт класса?

Tags: java, поиск-библиотек

Есть ли библиотеки для java позволяющие на этапе компиляции определить, что некий класс импортируется там, где это не желательно?

Как я это вижу:

```
@VisibleFor(some.packagee.name)
public class AlmostPublic {
    // ...
}
```

И теперь попытка импортировать класс `AlmostPublic` в любом месте за пределами пакета `some.packagee.name` должна вызвать ошибку компиляции.

Comment: А как библиотека может повлиять на базовый функционал языка, приводя к ошибке компиляции на строке `import`?

Comment: Похоже на то, что вы пытаетесь заново изобрести `default`.

Comment: Просто объявите protected конструктор и создать объект можно будет только в пакете

Comment: Не понятно зачем это может понадобится

Comment: В java 9 появилась модульная система. Можете попробовать организовывать модули так, что он будет доступен только там, где позволено

Comment: @ArchDemon, до android-а не скоро эти модули доберутся))

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, дабы не было соблазна из презентера базу дергать и тому прочие не богоугодные вещи творить.

Comment: Наверное тут может помочь checkstyle и build breaker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы хотите следить за командой разработчиков, к которым у вас есть доступ, то вы можете [скачать](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1065-checkstyle-idea) расширение для IntelliJ - *Chekstyle-IDEA*(вы так же можете [скачать](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) его для Maven). Суть такая: вы запускаете проверку, и Chekstyle показывает вам ошибки, т.е. где по "её" мнению код написан в неверном стиле(это по умолчанию). Но вы можете добавить туда собственные фильтры, например `import ...`. Вы даже [можете настроить](https://habr.com/sandbox/78503/) IDEA так, что бы проверки пред компиляцией выполняла Chekstyle(т.е. точно так же, как у вас из-за ошибки не компилируется код, у вас он не будет компилироваться из-за импорта класса, если вы это все настроили).

Если вы пишите (допустим) библиотеку, т.е. вы не сможете следить за разработкой программ, кот. используют ваш класс, то как уже [писали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/883262/%D0%9E%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-public-%D0%B2-java#comment1437941_883262), вы не можете запретить создание импортов на уровне компиляции. Тогда вы можете запретить создавать объекты своего класса, т.е. определить дефолтный конструктор как default(т.е., вообще без модификатора) - сделать его доступным только внутри пакета(package).

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю свои пять копеек

Плагины к среде разработки это конечно все отлично, но, если вы пытаетесь построить рабочий процесс и хотите быть уверены что все ему следуют то это слегка не тот путь.

Есть средства сборки , например Jenkins, у вас при сборке есть стадия, которая запускает SonarCube , который в свою очередь использует принятые у вас в команде проверки кода.

Самое главное тут что дальше у вас есть так называемые quality gate, и build breaker , которые сломают сборку, если правила игры нарушены. И разработчик получает email сообщение что он не прав

Как то так